# ASUS screen goes half black when is charging

Tags: laptop, display, charging, black-screen-of-death, asus

When I charge my laptop, bottom screen goes half black [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4en1W.jpg)

Comment: Try this: Use a screenshot and if the picture looks bad there too it's software related, if it looks normal then you should go to a repair shop to get it fixed.
Also what other stuff have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The machine appears to be working so most of it is OK.

Update BIOS, Chipset, Video, Power Driver and all other drivers.

The restart the computer, clear all power management settings (back to default).  Restart again, set up Power management and check.

I think Power Drivers and setup to be much more likely than a GPU failure because you plugged in the charger.

I do assume you are using the OEM Charger for your laptop.

When that is all done, if you still see the half screen, there would be a hardware problem of some kind needing service.